# How to use variables in CGRectMake function - attempting to output data in table-like structure

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to output a list of an account's 'friends' by pragmatically creating and stacking labels. I have fetched the accounts' friends from a MySQL database (accessible via NSURL interacting with a PHP script) and loaded them into an array. The goal is to loop through the array and create a label that is positioned slightly below the previous one each iteration. The problem I have run into is when I pass a variable into the CGRectMake function to create the label, it will not accept the int because it is not of type "CGFloat". I feel like I have tried just about everything, but I can never cast the data type correctly.
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class viewFriendsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let friendsArray = ["billy", "joe", "bob", "jim"]
        var inc = 0
        for index in friendsArray {
            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            let yPos: CGFloat = Float(inc * 10)
            label.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, yPos)
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = "\(index)"
            self.view.addSubview(label)
            inc = inc + 1 // I have not been able to play with the label yet to determine how to move it's vertical position because I cannot run the program due to the casting error.
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var inc = 0
    for index in friendsArray {
        let label: UILabel = UILabel()

        //type conversion is 
        let yPos = CGFloat(inc * 10)

        label.frame = CGRectMake(50,yPos,200,50)  // if you want to change the Y-Coodinates use in Y frame not in height
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "\(index)"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        inc = inc + 1 
    }
```

the above choice is not work try this

```
  var inc : CGFloat = 0
    for index in friendsArray {
        let label: UILabel = UILabel()

        label.frame = CGRectMake(50,inc,200,50)  // if you want to change the Y-Coodinates use in Y frame not in height
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "\(index)"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        inc = inc * 10  //  inc + 10
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take advantage of the new notation for CGRect in swift instead of using legacy c macros, these allow for usage with Int, Double and Float:

```
CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 20, height: 40)
```

Note that these frames are now created using standard swift init functions for structs.

Comment: Still getting an error that the ints are not convertible to CGFloat. Thank you for your help

Comment: ok? Try this: `CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 200.0, width: 20.0, height: 40.0)`

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it with `CGFloat()` instead of `Float()` and it works:

```
var inc = 0
var ypos: CGFloat = CGFloat(inc * 10)
var rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(50, ypos, 200, 200)
```

Also note you are currently using your `ypos` at the position of the `height`. Remember it is

```
CGRectMake(<xPos>, <yPos>, <width>, <height>)
```